# Newly created site collection throws page not found error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have created a new sitecollection in SharePoint 2013 and when I try to access facing page not found error in IE and in Chrome.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Date: Tue, 06 Dec 2016 07:11:43 GMT
Connection: close
```

Comment: Please check Log...You may get more specific error for this.

Comment: this is mean the site collection is not created properly , try to delete it from central administration > application management > site collection > delete site collection then create it a gain , if you face the same issue check the log

Answer (score 0):

please `reset IIS` and check the result.

Make sure `Workstation` service is started in server > administrator tools > services.